# How do I query this correctly?

Tags: java, database, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, querying

What I would like, is that the query/app shows all the lessons in the future,

**but also** checks all results between now and + 24h.
If a lesson in that time window has `Aantal == 0`. I don't want to query/show it.
Do you have any idea how to do this? Is it even possible?

**I have this query now:**

```
private Date Ledendatum(){
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    return cal.getTime();
}

 query = fStore.collection("Lessen").orderBy("Wanneer").startAt(new Date(Ledendatum));
```

**This is my firestore:**
[image]

Comment: Hi, did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're working with java, have you tried

cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)

Check this link https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-add-days-to-current-date/

Comment: 'Thanks, but that is the only thing I did know how to do. I don"t know how to combine the query's into a logical sentence that java and firestore understand.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a [not equal condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_):

```
fStore.collection("Lessen")
  .orderBy("Wanneer")
  .where("Aantal", "!=", 0)
  .startAt(new Date(Ledendatum))
```

Comment: Yes, almost! But I do want to see the lessons that have , aantal  = 0,  after the first 24hours.  So they cannot all disappear.